# Chrome DevTools Protocol: switch 'active' frame

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, selenium, google-chrome-devtools, nightwatch.js

I'm using Chrome Headless and `chrome-remote-interface` **npm** package

```
const chromeLauncher = require('chrome-launcher')
const CDP = require('chrome-remote-interface')
const fs = require('fs')

async function launchChrome() {
  return chromeLauncher.launch({
    port: 9222,
    chromeFlags: ['--disable-gpu', '--headless']
  })
}

(async function () {
    const chrome = await launchChrome()
    const client = await CDP({port: 9222})
    const {Page} = client
    await Page.enable()
    await Page.navigate({url: 'http://...'})
    await Page.loadEventFired()
    const {data} = await Page.captureScreenshot()
    fs.writeFileSync('screenshot.png', Buffer.from(data, 'base64'))
    await protocol.close()
    await chrome.kill()
})()
```

But the page I'm loading contains an **iframe** and I want to perform some actions inside it (**click** some elements or access them via **DOM.querySelector**) before taking the screenshot.

Is it possible to switch current 'active' frame somehow via Chrome DevTools Protocol? Like it is possible in Nightwatch.js/Selenium: `browser.frame(frameIndex)`

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but looking at [the documentation](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/DOM/#type-NodeId) I'd say get the iframe node via DOM.querySelector then use the iframe.contentDocument as the base node for the subsequent DOM.querySelector.

Comment: DOM.querySelector(All) returns just nodeId(s), so there is no contentDocument. I've tried something like this:
`const iframes = await client.DOM.querySelectorAll({nodeId: root.root.nodeId, selector: 'iframe'});
const buttons = await client.DOM.querySelectorAll({nodeId: iframes.nodeIds[0], selector: '.some-button'})`
But it returns an empty array

Comment: You can probably get the Node reference via DOM.resolveNode or dig DOM.getDocument result manually.

Comment: I'm not sure if I actually need JavaScript node reference. What I want is to click on a button inside an iframe. I'm thinking about 2 ways: 1) get nodeId for the button (don't know how), find its coordinates via DOM.getBoxModel, call Input.dispatchMouseEvent(x,y)  2) another way is do it from JavaScript inside browser via Runtime.evaluate(someJS), but not sure it if it will be possible due to security. Though both these ways are not as convenient (even is they would work) as if there was ability to switch current active frame like in some other automation tools.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: I used this lib, which supports iframes https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-headless-chrome